# WSO2 Identity Server oAuth2: how to keep original access token from IDP

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

Our app implements OAuth 2.0 code grant flow.

In identity server we use Identity Provider with `OAuth2/OpenID` Connect federated authenticator `Azure AD`. `Azure AD` successfully sends access token from `login.microsoftonline.com/.../oauth2/v2.0/token` endpoint to identity server's callback uri.

IS replaces this token with own value and sends it back to the application. The problem is we need to use original token from `Azure` to query `MS graph API`. So the question is how to force IS to keep original access token or is there any way to fetch it somehow from there?

Comment: If you want the original access token from the IDP, why not simply connect the app to that IDP directly rather than going through IS?

Comment: @farasath, We have multiple instances of our software, and they all use the same IDP. We have to request access to AD separately for every instance, specifying different redirect_url. It takes time. Having one IS in between doing authorization against this IDP and would allow us to save a lot of time, since we can specify redirect_url by ourselves in this case